# can i use target display mode on mid 2011 IMac with an early 2011 macbook pro with thunderbolt

Tags: mac

I have connected the mid 2011 IMac to the early 2011 macbook pro via thunderbolt.  Nothing happens.  Command /  F2 on the IMac doesn't do anything.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Are you using a thunderbolt to thunder cable? The reason I am asking is that display port cables do not support this mode. See the article below.http://support.apple.com/kb/TS3775

Comment: Also are you running the latest version of your os, run software update and apply any updates then run software update again as there have been some thunderbolt firmware updates.